# Query giving duplicate result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT b.id,b.body FROM btin b
INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

the problem is its printing duplicate result.
How can I optimize this one

please help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to solve this (basically you have more than 1 row in nwork):

```
SELECT distinct b.id,b.body FROM btin b
INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0


SELECT  b.id,b.body 
FROM btin b
Where b.id in (SELECT  b.id FROM btin b  INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
                WHERE b.parentid = '0' AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id)))
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

SELECT  b.id,b.body FROM btin b
INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))
Group by b.id, b.body, b.date
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id,b.body FROM btin b
....
```

what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try with either

```
SELECT DISTINCT .......
```

OR

```
SELECT b.id,b.body FROM btin b
INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id)) 
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use group by instead:

```
SELECT b.id,b.body FROM btin b
INNER JOIN nwork n ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id)  
WHERE b.parentid = '0'
AND ('401' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id))
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```