# MySQL query giving duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying four tables (activities, notes, categories, user_entries) looking for matches that are EITHER activities OR notes. In my development database, I have 8 activities and 2 notes that match: instead I get 16 results. Each activity is duplicated: one result including the first note, the other including the second.

This is the query as it stands:

```
SELECT a.`aid`, a.`activityname`, a.`date`, u.`points`, u.`enid`, c.`catname`, n.`nid`, n.`notename`, n.`dates`
FROM activities a
INNER JOIN user_entries u ON a.`aid` = u.`aid_FK`
INNER JOIN categories c ON a.`category` = c.`cat`
INNER JOIN notes n ON u.`mem_no_FK` = n.`mem_no_FK`
WHERE u.`mem_no_FK` = 1995
GROUP BY a.`aid`, a.`activityname`, a.`date`, u.`points`, u.`enid`, c.`catname`, n.`nid`, n.`notename`, n.`dates`
ORDER BY `date`
```

I have looked at quite a few similar questions here, (especially [question 7696248](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696248/query-giving-duplicate-result)): but nothing I've tried has worked. Despite trying many suggestions (with/without DISTINCT, with/without GROUP BY, many join types, etc.) I get the same result each time: there is something basically wrong with the query. My knowledge of SQL is not good and I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: FOR CLARITY
The database is a record of continuing professional development activities. Notes (confusingly named, but not by me!) are not linked to activities: they are there for users to record significant events- "No CPD done for 3 months due to road accident", and so on.

I need to list the notes and the activities on the same page: if it's possible, I'd prefer to run one DB query; if it isn't, I'll have to run two queries and amalgamate the two results arrays.

Comment: Please can you provide example data from all three tables?

Comment: make an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: That is intended behaviour: you group on aid and notes, what else did you expect? How do you want to represent the different notes in one row? Also the `GROUP BY` clause is redundant as you're selecting exactly the same things as int he group by, thus making the latter useless.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `DISTINCT` for `aid`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.`aid`), a.`activityname`, a.`date`, u.`points`, u.`enid`, c.`catname`, n.`nid`, n.`notename`, n.`dates`
FROM activities a
INNER JOIN user_entries u ON a.`aid` = u.`aid_FK`
INNER JOIN categories c ON a.`category` = c.`cat`
INNER JOIN notes n ON u.`mem_no_FK` = n.`mem_no_FK`
WHERE u.`mem_no_FK` = 1995
GROUP BY a.`aid`, a.`activityname`, a.`date`, u.`points`, u.`enid`, c.`catname`, n.`nid`, n.`notename`, n.`dates`
ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this: shows the duplicates as before .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all notes in one column you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` or [other aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT a.`aid`, a.`activityname`, a.`date`, u.`points`, u.`enid`, c.`catname`, GROUP_CONCAT(n.`notename` SEPARATOR ' ') as notes
FROM activities a
JOIN user_entries u ON a.`aid` = u.`aid_FK`
JOIN categories c ON a.`category` = c.`cat`
JOIN notes n ON u.`mem_no_FK` = n.`mem_no_FK`
WHERE u.`mem_no_FK` = 1995
GROUP BY a.`aid`
ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: This does return the 8 activities, but not the notes.

Comment: Please look at my (and the other comments) for your question. We cannot answer it adequatly now...